# Can't Use Parseint

Tags: android, parseint

I m just a beginner .And whenever I run this program it just ends...
Please help...

the error is below ,,whenever i delete this ,the program works

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    principal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.princi);
    Tame = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
    ratee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rate);

    interst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.interest);
    amunt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);

    //The error is here 
     prncpl = principal.getText().toString();
     rte = ratee.getText().toString();
     tme = Tame.getText().toString();

     tme2 = Integer.parseInt(tme);
     prncpl2 =Integer.parseInt(prncpl);
     rte2 = Integer.parseInt(rte);
    //Ends here
```

Comment: Please include your error message

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to parse an int from a double, etc? If its a decimal value or something that isn't a whole number, you need to use the Double version of this method

```
Double.parseDouble(String)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're getting an error because you're trying to use `parseInt()` on an empty string.

these lines of code:

> ```
>  prncpl = principal.getText().toString();
>  rte = ratee.getText().toString();
>  tme = Tame.getText().toString();
>
>  tme2 = Integer.parseInt(tme);
>  prncpl2 =Integer.parseInt(prncpl);
>  rte2 = Integer.parseInt(rte);
> ```

should not be in your `onCreate()` method, `principal.getText().toString()` gets the value the user types in the EditText, you should call it and parse it in the onClickListener of a Button or something.